# Advertisement trial group

Tags: single-word-requests

When conducting a user study about how a target audience will react to an ad, the ad can be pushed to a small sample of the target audience first.

> Our ____ group reacted better to the red one

It's not: study group, trial group, sample group, research group

Comment: You need to explain _**why**_  _it's not_: 'study group', 'trial group', 'sample group', or  'research group'. 'Test group' is another possibility, but very close to 'trial group'. These all seem to work well for an educated Anglophone not well up on advertising/business jargon. If you're after a specific fixed phrase 'X group' used in such jargon, it could well be that a dedicated site is more suitable for this request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [Focus Group](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus%20group).

Merriam-Webster describes it as a small group of people whose responses are studied to anticipate the larger response from the target population [rephrased].

Comment: Yes, and that is all it is. None of the others work at all here.

Answer (score 1):

Our **pilot group** reacted better to the red one.

> - [pilot](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pilot) -  "serving as an experimental or trial undertaking prior to full-scale operation or use: a pilot project."

[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+pilot+group%22&sxsrf=AOaemvJNuKxtMbFiYjJsO4UqqE85eDhbIw:1641747372044&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjElK_HkaX1AhU0r5UCHWn4A-wQ_AUoAXoECAIQCw&biw=1536&bih=722&dpr=1.25#:%7E:text=all%20members%20know%20they%20are%20in%20a%20pilot%20group%20experience.) "...all members know they are in a pilot group experience."
[2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+pilot+group%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvLQf6AFxb32rpVfj8wFV_jxD17A-g:1641747378435&ei=shPbYfPiGbTW1sQPmJqiqAo&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjzg7XKkaX1AhU0q5UCHRiNCKUQ8tMDegQIARBD&biw=1536&bih=722&dpr=1.25#:%7E:text=Using%20a%20pilot%20group%20was%20an%20attempt%20to%20isolate%20potential%20problems)  "Using a pilot group was an attempt to isolate potential problems."
[3](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+pilot+group%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvLQf6AFxb32rpVfj8wFV_jxD17A-g:1641747378435&ei=shPbYfPiGbTW1sQPmJqiqAo&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjzg7XKkaX1AhU0q5UCHRiNCKUQ8tMDegQIARBD&biw=1536&bih=722&dpr=1.25#:%7E:text=Running%20a%20pilot%20means%20choosing%20a%20small%20group%20of%20users) "Running a pilot means choosing a small group of users..."